In python, how do you assert the type of a variable after checking it?
Overview
There is a general pattern in programming that goes like this
if (something is not initialized) {
    initialize the thing
}
do something with the initialized thing

In python, I have an object that's of type A | B. I then call some initialization function that guarantees it will be of type A. Then I want to access a member of the object. However, the type of the variable is not narrowed down to just A. I want to signal to python that I know it is A and not A | B. How can I do that?
Example
Here is some sample code that demonstrates the problem.
import random

# Start with a variable that is "uninitialized"
# (it might be str and it might be None)
value: str | None = None if random.random() > 0.5 else "goodbye"

# Create a function that initializes it. After this function runs,
# the variable will be of type str. It cannot be None.
def set():
    global value
    value = "hello"

# Check if the variable is initialized. This is the part mentioned
# in the Overview section. Here I am taking some action that will
# guarantee that value is of type str. However, python does not
# know that. It only knows I am calling a function and not using
# the result. But I as the programmer know that the external effect
# of calling set() will be that value can no longer be None
if value is None:
    set()

# Now that I have initialized my value, I want to do something with
# it. Let's say I want to capitalize it, since I know it's a str
result = value.capitalize()

# Print out the result
print(result)

Uh oh! When the code runs, it prints "Hello" or "Goodbye" correctly; however, there is an error on this line:
result = value.capitalize()

The error says Cannot access attribute "capitalize" for class "None" Attribute "capitalize" is unknown (Pyright reportAttributeAccessIssue)
Right, of course. Python doesn't know about what set() does, and it still assumes that my value is str | None when I as the programmer know that it is in fact just str.
Note
In the example above, I can remove the if value is None check and the same question applies. set() still guarantees that value is of type str.
Context
In TypeScript, I would do this:
let value: string | null = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'goodbye' : null;

const set = () => {
    value = 'hello';
};

if (value === null) {
    set();
}
const result = (value as string).toUpperCase();
console.log(result);

The key point is the type assertion value as string. Without that part, it will complain that toUpperCase is not valid on null, just like how python is complaining that capitalize is not valid on None.
Question
What is the idiomatic or normal way to do this kind of assertion? How can I signal to python that my value has been initialized/modified/set and that its type is now A instead of A | B?

One option not covered by the duplicate is not defining value before you are "ready" with an actual str value. This comes up more with instance attributes that get set after object creation, when something like the Builder pattern could be used to wait until all attribute values are available before constructing the final object.

I as the programmer know that the external effect of calling set() will be that value can no longer be None -- the idiomatic way of expressing this type of knowledge is to assert it -- in this case you'd simply say assert value is not None.  If you're wrong, you'll have an uncaught AssertionError that halts your program, so the type checker will check the remainder of your program under the assumption that you were right.
